# Auto fill People Picker Column with current user in 2013 in new and Edit Form

Tags: 2013, jquery

I want to auto fill the new People picker column in SharePoint 2013. I want to do it in Edit and New form. It could be current user or anyother user.

Comment: jsLink is the technology for field/list manipulation. here's a reference for your case - https://umeaworks.wordpress.com/2015/03/17/setting-default-value-of-person-field-in-sharepoint-2013-with-jslink/

Answer (score 4):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function SetAndResolvePeoplePicker(fieldName, userAccountName) {
    var controlName = fieldName;
    var peoplePickerDiv = $("[id$='ClientPeoplePicker'][title='" + controlName + "']");
    var peoplePickerEditor = peoplePickerDiv.find("[title='" + controlName + "']");
    var spPeoplePicker = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[peoplePickerDiv[0].id];
    peoplePickerEditor.val(userAccountName);
    spPeoplePicker.AddUnresolvedUserFromEditor(true);
    //disable the field
    spPeoplePicker.SetEnabledState(true);
    //hide the delete/remove use image from the people picker
    //$('.sp-peoplepicker-delImage').css('display','none');
}
function GetCurrentUser(userid) {
    var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/getuserbyid(" + userid + ")";
    var requestHeaders = { "accept" : "application/json;odata=verbose" };
    $.ajax({
        url : requestUri,
        contentType : "application/json;odata=verbose",
        headers : requestHeaders,
        success : onSuccess,
        error : onError
    });
}

function onSuccess(data, request){
    var loginName = data.d.LoginName.split('|')[1];
    //alert(loginName);
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('clientpeoplepicker.js', 'SPClientPeoplePicker', function ()
    {
            //your code goes here
            SetAndResolvePeoplePicker("AssignTo",loginName);
     });

   // return loginName;
}

function onError(error) {
    alert(error);
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    var userid = _spPageContextInfo.userId;
    GetCurrentUser(userid);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

With respect to Marc D Anderson and his [SPServices](https://github.com/sympmarc/SPServices/wiki/SPFindPeoplePicker) library:

```
var currentUser = jQuery().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({
    fieldName: "Title",
    debug: false
});

var pickerDisplayName = "Requester Name";

var peoplePicker = jQuery().SPServices.SPFindPeoplePicker({
    peoplePickerDisplayName: pickerDisplayName,
    valueToSet: currentUser,
    checkNames: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I use what Taran basically showed, but I found 2 problems in our environment.

Timing - it wouldn't work for some users. I had to call the function with a timing loop, so if it got an error it would retry.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   window.setTimeout(function(){ updatePeoplePicker(0,10,200);},200);
});
```

and in the function, I had to catch the errors are reloop:

```
function updatePeoplePicker( loopValue,MaxLoops, TimeDelay) {
    try {.... }
    catch(err) {

      loopValue++;

      //Total Time allowed for retrys is 2 seconds
      if(loopValue > MaxLoops)
      {
        window.setTimeout(function(){ doTheDefaults2(loopValue,MaxLoops,TimeDelay);},TimeDelay);
      }
     }
    }
```

And currently in SP2013, you have to find the editor differently - it now uses a bit different name - it adds `, Enter a name or email address...` to the field name.

```
var controlName2 = "Requested By, Enter a name or email address...";    
var ppEditor = ppDiv.find("[title='" + controlName2 + "']");
```